# Scroll from div to next div (different height)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got page with 5 div's. My div's have different heigh (it's adaptive). How I can go to next div by mouse when I scroll half of the current div?

I trying fullpage.js and onepage.js but it not working for me, because my div must be different height

```css
#first {
width:100vw;
height:700px;
background-color:lightyellow;
text-align:center;
}

#second {
width:100vw;
height:700px;
background-color:lightblue;
text-align:center;
}

#third {
width:100vw;
height:1000px;
background-color:lightpink;
text-align:center;
}

#fourht {
width:100vw;
height:1500px;
background-color:lightgreen;
text-align:center;
}

#fiveth {
width:100vw;
height:800px;
background-color:lightgray;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">1 div</div>
<div id="second">2 div</div>
<div id="third">3 div</div>
<div id="fourht">4 div</div>
<div id="fiveth">5 div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you're need get the height current **active** elem, and give for container transform translate( 0, -**height** ) on scroll, onepage and fullpage for there are work with this.

Comment: onepage and fullpage for full screen (1 section == 1 screen), but it not for me

Comment: i told, you can get height active elem, and give container, if you want simple finished code, yes it not for you

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $container = $('.container');
var $elem = $container.find('.elem');
var $active = $container.find('.active').height();

$(window).on('scroll',function(){
  $container.css({"transform":"translate(0, -" + $active + "px)"});
});
```

```css
body{
      height: 100%;
}
.container{
    transition: 1s all;
}
#first {
width:100vw;
height:700px;
background-color:lightyellow;
text-align:center;
}

#second {
width:100vw;
height:700px;
background-color:lightblue;
text-align:center;
}

#third {
width:100vw;
height:1000px;
background-color:lightpink;
text-align:center;
}

#fourht {
width:100vw;
height:1500px;
background-color:lightgreen;
text-align:center;
}

#fiveth {
width:100vw;
height:800px;
background-color:lightgray;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div id="first" class="elem active">1 div</div>
<div id="second" class="elem">2 div</div>
<div id="third" class="elem">3 div</div>
<div id="fourht" class="elem">4 div</div>
<div id="fiveth" class="elem">5 div</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created my version. Look at this https://codepen.io/damates/pen/VXdKjR .

Jquery:

```
$("#nextDiv, #previousDiv").click(function(){
  actualTopOffset = $(window).scrollTop();
  areas = $(".area");
  find = false;
  newPosition = 0;
  type = $(this).attr("data-type");
  areasCount = $(areas).length;
  $.each(areas, function(index, val) { 

    if(type == "next"){//if we click to go next area
      if($(areas).length > (index+1)){
        if(actualTopOffset < $(areas[index+1]).offset().top && !find){// ask if area has top offset higher. If yes set new position
          find = true;
          newPosition = $(areas[index+1]).offset().top;

        }
      }
     }else if(type == "prev"){ //if we click to go previous area
       areasCount--;
       if((areasCount) >= 0){
          if(actualTopOffset > $(areas[areasCount]).offset().top && !find){// ask if area has top offset lower. If yes set new position
            find = true;
            newPosition = $(areas[areasCount]).offset().top;
          }
        }
     }

    });

  if(find){ //If we found new position scroll on new position
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: newPosition
    }, 1000);
  }

});
```

CSS:

```
    #first {
    width:100vw;
    height:700px;
    background-color:lightyellow;
    text-align:center;
}

#second {
    width:100vw;
    height:700px;
    background-color:lightblue;
    text-align:center;
}

#third {
    width:100vw;
    height:1000px;
    background-color:lightpink;
    text-align:center;
}

#fourht {
    width:100vw;
    height:1500px;
    background-color:lightgreen;
    text-align:center;
}

#fiveth {
    width:100vw;
    height:800px;
    background-color:lightgray;
    text-align:center;
}

#nextDiv, #previousDiv{
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  background: red;
}

#previousDiv{
  top: 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="first" class="area">1 div</div>
<div id="second" class="area">2 div</div>
<div id="third" class="area">3 div</div>
<div id="fourht" class="area">4 div</div>
<div id="fiveth" class="area">5 div</div>
<div id="previousDiv" data-type="prev">Previous div</div>
```

### Next div

EDIT VERSION WITH SCROLL

I change the script for scrolling. Look at to https://codepen.io/damates/pen/VXdKjR

Comment: I must do it without button, only mouse wheel